# How do I exclude some responses from a function that pulls that from a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, list, date

I am trying to only show the dates to the uses of this Python application. For some reason, the code returns responses like "Date" and "None" from the spreadsheet. Date is in the column that I am trying to draw the dates from. Here is the code:

```
    sh = gc.open("Deposits")
    worksheet = sh.worksheet("Sheet2")
    values_list = worksheet.col_values(3)
    set = set(values_list)
    result = list(set)
    print "Here are all the possible dates to check:",result
```

Result:

`['3/10/2012', '2/18/2013', '3/18/2011', '3/17/2010', 'Date', None, '2/9/2010']`

How do I get this function to only return the dates and exclude 'Date' and 'None'?

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract a set that contains the things you don't want to include.

```
myset = set(values_list) - {None, 'Date'}
```

Also, don't use variable names that are already assigned to built-in functions, like `set`, or you'll run into problems when you want to use that built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get rid of `"Date"` and `None`

```
a = ['3/10/2012', '2/18/2013', '3/18/2011', '3/17/2010', 'Date', None, '2/9/2010']
r = list(set([i for i in a if i not in("Date",None)]))
['3/10/2012', '2/18/2013', '3/18/2011', '3/17/2010', '2/9/2010']
```